# Adding Tracking to sales_flat_order table

Tags: magento-1.9, flat

We use an module call iparcel for International Orders.

These orders get immediate tracking information and this updates in the correct tables needed for normal tracking use case, however, we use a middle-ware service called celigo  to map order data to our ERP, Netsuite(NS).

Celigo uses sales_flat_order table to gather all records involved with order data , to import via an API call, and tracking is not a default field in this table.

I've managed to figure out how to correctly add the table based on a few fields in iParcels sql scripts, but I can not figure out what model to use to write to these tables.

Here you see where iParcel writes the tracking

```
 protected function _submitParcel($shipment, $order)
    {
        $api = Mage::helper('iparcel/api');
        $response = $api->submitParcel($shipment);

        // Find the name of the Service Level as defined in the Admin
        $serviceLevels = Mage::helper('iparcel')->getServiceLevels();
        $responseServiceLevelId = $response->ServiceLevels[0][0]->ServiceLevelID;
        $serviceLevelTitle = 'I-Parcel';
        if (array_key_exists($responseServiceLevelId, $serviceLevels)) {
            $serviceLevelTitle = $serviceLevels[$responseServiceLevelId];
        }

        // Add tracking number from submitParcel response
        Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->addTrack(
            $shipment->getIncrementId(),
            $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
            $serviceLevelTitle,
            $response->CarrierTrackingNumber
        );
    }
```

What I am asking is, is there a way to directly update this field right after it writes tracking , so its there before celigo imports the order ?

Comment: A more efficient way is to modify Celigo to do a table join from sales_flat_shipment_track to sales_flat_order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't change the code in celigo, then execute the following 3 mySQL statements in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE `sales_flat_order` ADD `track_number` text;  
UPDATE `sales_flat_order` o
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_shipment_track` t
ON o.entity_id = t.order_id
SET o.track_number = t.track_number;
CREATE TRIGGER track_number_insert AFTER INSERT ON `sales_flat_shipment_track` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `sales_flat_order` o INNER JOIN `sales_flat_shipment_track` t ON o.entity_id = t.order_id SET o.track_number = t.track_number;
END$$
```

Note: the above is **not** tested.

Comment: This works! Ive been banging my head for 4 days trying to figure this out.

Comment: could you clarify what the o and t reference to ? just so I know what this code fully means

Comment: Glad that it works for you. `o` refers to `sales_flat_order`, `t` refers to `sales_flat_shipment_track`.

Comment: Also, what are the double dollar signs for ? I tried to look into but did not find anything that explained its use here

Comment: $$ is the delimiter, you can define other delimiter. See [online doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/begin-end.html)

Comment: Thank you very very very much. I learned quite a bit from this thread. I hope good fortune comes your way !